# org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm using Maven 2.2.1 and I sucessfully ran:

```
mvn -B release:clean release:prepare
```

But get the error message:

> No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from

when I run:

```
mvn release:perform
```

My `pom.xml` have the `scm` tags defined correctly:

```xml
<scm>
    <url>file:///C:/tmp/svnrepo/myproj/trunk</url>        
    <connection>scm:svn:file:///C:/tmp/svnrepo/myproj/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:file:///C:/tmp/svnrepo/myproj/trunk</developerConnection>        
</scm>
```

Comment: Please, add maven-release-plugin configuration too.

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to rerun a maven `release:perform` by creating a manually edited `release.properties` file in the root folder. This file should define these two properties: `scm.url` and `scm.tag`. Here a possible example:

```
scm.url=scm:git:https://github.com/owner/repo.git
scm.tag=v1.0.4
```

With this file it is possible to redo a `release:perform` task.

*Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18943705).*

Comment: without property file: `mvn release:perform -DconnectionUrl=scm:git:git@github.com:your_org/your_repo.git -Dtag=10.3.3`

Answer (score 8):

Looks like I did a `mvn -DdryRun=true release:perform` and this had deleted the release.properties file from the prepare stage.

So I add the -DconnectionUrl to the command to provide url of the tag

Answer (score 7):

It should work. I had similar problem, but in my case perform failed due to network error and I had to restart it with something like:

```
mvn release:perform -rf :{ARTIFACT ON WHICH IT FAILED} -DconnectionUrl=scm:svn:{URL TO TAG}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply running `mvn release:clean release:prepare` first, and then `mvn release:perform` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The message

> No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from

does not mean the SCM URL in the `pom.xml`!

There are two kinds of SCM-URLS:

1. Trunk Folder (for development)
2. Tag Folder (for tagging the release)

In the pom.xml you specify the trunk-folder-url. What the release:perform require is the tag-folder-url. You can specify the parameter [-DconnectionUrl](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#connectionUrl).

Usually you are using `prepare` and `perform` in one maven call. Prepare do all preparation stuff and will commit some resources to the version-control-system using the comment `[maven-release-plugin] prepare release XXX`- **BUT NOT ALL FILES ARE COMMITTED**! One important file is **not** committed to the version-control-system, the `release.properties`. This file is used if you omit the [-DconnectionUrl](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#connectionUrl).

The problem occourse while `perform` because the checkout/commit require the `release.properties` or the [-DconnectionUrl](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#connectionUrl) respectivly.

You can either:

1. Specify the tag-url by using [-DconnectionUrl](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#connectionUrl) or
2. Call `release:prepare release:perform` in one shot to rely on the not-committed `release.properties`

More informations [are here](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got this same exception in our CI automation and it turned out to be due to the fact that `target/checkout` directory already has a release build. For one of the projects, we had to introduce an improvised maven release perform build between the real maven `release:prepare` and `release:perform` steps. As part of improvisation the release tag is checked out to `target/checkout` and what I noticed is that if this directory is left undeleted, it would cause the `release:perform` to fail with the `No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from` error. I don't know if it matters, but we also use `-DlocalCheckout=true` option.

Answer (score 0):

My case
I missed **release:prepare**

Full command which is I used

```
mvn -U -e release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=<RELEASE_VERSION> -DdevelopmentVersion=<DEVELOPMENT_VERSION> -Dtag=<TAG_NAME>
```